# Which access method is appropriate for a table with two or more B-Tree Indexes

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Consider the customer table below shown below. This table contains about 750 000 rows and a unique B-Tree index has been automatically created on its primary key. In addition, suppose that the DBA has created a B-Tree index on Other_Names + Surname.

---

### CUSTOMER Table

'#'Customer_ID

*Surname

*Other_Names

*Username

*Address

.

.

.

---

### QUESTION

A user executes a query of the form:



SELECT ... FROM Customer

WHERE (Surname = 'SMITH');

-Identify all of the physical data access methods of that Oracle11g is able to use in this situation.

-Identify which of these access methods Oracle11g will be most likely to use;
and

-explain why this access method is more likely to be used compared to the other available access methods.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you got so far? What effort have you made to answer this yourself?

Comment: @Ollie In this query, hashing method cannot be used because hashing is only setup on the primary key which is the Customer_ID. A sequential method may be used but it will be slow as it scans the whole table even if it only ask for “Smith” as the surname. This means that most of the rows in the tables are filtered out, leaving the person with the surname “Smith”. This explains that the column has high selectivity and B-tree index in this column is a good choice to use, which makes more sense if we use index method.

Comment: Not sure if my answer was correct. I am a little confused about composite key indexes and would there be no benefit in using the B-Tree index on Surname as the query would use the left-Most index. In that case it would use the PK which in turn would provide no benefit to the second composite index...

Comment: The right answer is "Run an EXPLAIN PLAN and FIND OUT"! Your and your instructor's mileage may vary. Best of luck.